# Comparing two files script and finding the unmatched data

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am having two .txt files with data stored in the format

*1.txt*

```
ASF001-AS-ST73U12
ASF001-AS-ST92U14
ASF001-AS-ST105U33
ASF001-AS-ST107U20
```

and

*2.txt*

```
ASF001-AS-ST121U21
ASF001-AS-ST130U14
ASF001-AS-ST73U12
ASF001-AS-ST92U14
```

`
I need to find the files which are in *1.txt* but not in *2.txt*.

I tried to use

```
diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y 1.txt 2.txt > finaloutput
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than diff you can use `comm` here:

```
comm -23 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
ASF001-AS-ST105U33
ASF001-AS-ST107U20
```

Or this `awk` will also work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $1 in a{delete a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i}' 1.txt 2.txt
ASF001-AS-ST107U20
ASF001-AS-ST105U33
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple bash script can do what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line || test -n "$line"; do 
    grep -q $line "$2" || echo "$line"
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ ./uniquef12.sh dat/1.txt dat/2.txt
ASF001-AS-ST105U33
ASF001-AS-ST107U20
```